# If $|G|=p^n$, then for any $H<G$, there is a $K\leq G$ such that $H\lhd K$ and $[K:H]=p$

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

I have the following exercise:

> **Problem.** Group $G$ has order $p^n$, where $p$ is a prime number and $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that for any proper subgroup $H<G$ there is a subgroup $K\leq G$ such that $H\lhd K$ and $[K:H]=p$.

What I have done is consider center $Z(G)$ of $G$ and note that $Z(G)$ is nontrivial subgroup of $G$. For example, the statement is clear when $H\cap Z(G)=\{e\}$ or when $H\leq Z(G)$. However, it's not clear how to approach the problem in general case.

I think we should somehow induct on $n$ (maybe we can consider $G/Z(G)$), because the similar problem can be solved in this way:

> **Problem.** Group $G$ has order $p^n$, where $p$ is a prime number and $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that for any positive integer $m\leq n$ there is a subgroup $H\leq G$ such that $|H|=p^m$.

So, does this approach lead to solution? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:Induct on $n$ where,$|G|=p^n$.and centre of p groups are non trivial, so if $a\in Z(G)$ of order $p$, then order of $G/<a>$ is less than $G$

Answer (score 1):

Induct on $n$.

Take the quotient by ta subgroup of the center of size $p$ to obtain $G'$ and $H'$ and notice that there exists a subgroup $K'$ containing $H'$ of required index. And then reobtain $H$ by taking the union of the corresponding cosets. The subgroup is normal because of the lattice isomorphism theorem.

The base case when $n=1$ is clear.

---

In fact this is just an application of the lattic isomorphism theorem, you want to prove that for each dude there is a dude immediately above him, and this is clear because in the quotient lattice we have this.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something but what will happen if $G'=H'$ (in this case we cannot apply the inductive hypothesis)? Or it's impossible?